# flutter ProgressDialog seems to have static fields that impact all instance

Tags: flutter, dart, progressdialog

I've encounter problems where the ProgressDialog fails at run-time.  There are several issues but the biggest problem is that under the right circumstances the ProgressDialog will not close when dismiss is called.  Instead I see the log entry "ProgressDialog already dismissed".  Once this happens the application is frozen with the ProgressDialog spinning.

My testing suggests that previous activities are bleeding over and affecting all instances of ProgressDialog even though I create new instances of ProgressDialog when I want to use it.

The application here is the smallest app I can construct to show the problem.  In this example the dismiss works but once the 'message' field is set in one instance it bleed over into the other instance where the 'message' is not set.

Any insight would be greatly appreciated.

```
import 'dart:async';
import 'package:progress_dialog/progress_dialog.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: MyHomePage(),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatelessWidget {
  MyHomePage() ;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final test1Button = Material(
      borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(30.0),
        color: Color(0xff01A0C7),
      child: MaterialButton(
        onPressed: () {
          print("Test1");
          final ProgressDialog pr = new ProgressDialog(context);
          pr.style(message: "Test 01");
          pr.show();
          new Timer(Duration(seconds: 3), () {
                pr.dismiss();
          });
        },
        child: Text("Test 01"),
      ),
    );
    final test2Button = Material(
      borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(30.0),
      color: Color(0xff01A0C7),
      child: MaterialButton(
        onPressed: () {
          final ProgressDialog pr = new ProgressDialog(context);
          pr.show();
          new Timer(Duration(seconds: 3), () {
            pr.dismiss();
          });
        },
        child: Text("Test 02"),
          ),
        );

    return Scaffold(
      body: Center(
        child: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: <Widget>[
            test1Button,
            test2Button,
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: The version of progress dialog is 'progress_dialog: ^1.2.0'

Answer (score 0):

Well, when you check the progress dialog [source code](https://github.com/fayaz07/progress_dialog/blob/master/lib/progress_dialog.dart) you will set that:

1. `ProgressDialog` class has only one member variable, and it's dialog:

```
class ProgressDialog {
  _Body _dialog;
```

2. Any parameters you pass to a `ProgressDialog` constructor or `style` method don't affect the instance... but override top level variables!

```
String _dialogMessage = "Loading...";

class ProgressDialog {
  _Body _dialog;

  void style({
      String message,
      }) {
    _dialogMessage = message ?? _dialogMessage;
  }
}
```

This is not the best programming practice, gently speaking. I suggest abandon using this library, because it's really messy and as you said you have already encountered several issues with it.

So yeah, your suspicions were true: `ProgressDialog` actually has static fields that impact all instances.

Comment: Thanks for you response.  I'm new to Flutter and Dart so I'm trying to understand how the code works :-)  I don't understand why _Body is a class level variable rather than an instance variable.   I've experimented with small classes and when I try to duplicate this code the variable define in this manner seem to be instance variables.

Comment: I think I see the problem ...  the variables like _dialogMessage are defined in the file outside of the class.  Being new to Dart, I'm assuming that puts them in a global static context/scope.

Comment: That's right, you may think of top level variables as static variables.